# Problem in code to divide N conditionally

Tags: c++, time

So, I'm trying to solve the [following](https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc169/tasks/abc169_d) Problem Statement

For an integer N, find the number of times the following operation can be performed:

```
Select an integer z which satisfies the 3 conditions:

1. Z can be expressed as p^e where p is prime and e > 0
2. z is a factor of N
3. z is different from all previous zs

Now replace N with N / z
```

---

This is the code that I tried:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

const bool isPrime(long long num) {
    for (long long div = 2; div <= sqrt(num); div++) {
        if (num % div == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

std::vector<long long> getFactors(const long long number) {
    std::vector<long long> vec_of_divisors;
    for (long long i = 1; i <= number / 2; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            vec_of_divisors.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    vec_of_divisors.push_back(number);
    return vec_of_divisors;
}

bool hasPrimeFactors(long long num) {
    std::vector<long long> divisors = getFactors(num);
    std::vector<long long> prime_vec;
    for (const auto& divisor : divisors) {
        if (isPrime(divisor)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    long long N = 997764507000;
    //std::cin >> N;
    long count = 0;
    std::vector<long long> usedFactors;

    auto notUsed = [&](long long num) {
        for (auto& elem : usedFactors) {
            if (elem == num) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    };
    long long temp;
    do {
        temp = N;
        std::vector<long long> factors = getFactors(N);
        for (auto& factor : factors) {
            if ((factor != 1) && hasPrimeFactors(factor) && notUsed(factor)) {
                usedFactors.push_back(factor);
                N = N / factor;
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (temp != N);
    std::cout << count << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

It exceeds the time limit of `2secs`

It seems the code is really inefficient.
What am I missing?

I have tried debugging, but it takes a really long time after it reaches `10^11`

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? To find out where it goes wrong?

Comment: Well, then it means the `N` variable does not goes below or eq 1. Which means the `N / factor` does not go below . From there you have t oinvestigate the `getFactors` method.

Comment: Your `N>1` logic appears to be incorrect. For `N=32`, the answer is 2, but `N` never actually gets down to 1. You should check if `N` has *changed* in each iteration, and break if it hasn't.

Comment: @cigien, is [this](https://pastebin.com/BewrtK0P) fine?

Comment: Seems reasonable. Does it work for the bigger input?

Comment: Your algorithm is definitely inefficient. For each `p ^ e | N`, where `e` is the maximum possible, you need to find the largest triangular number less than `e`. Then sum them up.

Comment: This is a minor variation on find the prime factors. Look up how to do that. You instead find all factors, then find factors of the factors, and you call isPrime on a bunch of stuff. These extra loops on loops are a lot of wasted effort. (also the example shows that e should be maximized, but they didn't state that in the problem) (additional note, I prefer python for these problems for the default support of arbitrarily large integers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number `N` can be factored into `(p1 ^ e1)(p2 ^ e2) ...`. For each of these factors `p^e`, the most that you can divide `N` by is `(p)(p ^ 2)(p ^ 3)...`. Of course, all those powers need to sum to less than or equal to `e`.

So you only need to compute all the factors once, and then for each `e`, find the largest triangular number that is less than or equal to `e`. The repeated factor calculations are wasted work, and is unnecessary.